# Right way to program in MVC3, appropriate use of partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view, on the top there's a dropdownlist which basically allows user to select one of the two options.On now the basis of this selection i have to show the content on this page.

Now, what 'd be the right way to go, i should create two partial views and put them in separate divs and on the basis of selection i'd make one of them visible

Or, just have two divs and have my chtml markup inside them and make one of them visible on the basis of user selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use partial views, you could use ajax to load them into a single div containing the content instead of having them both already on the page and hidden.

The jquery call to the controller would look like this:

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("PartialViewMethod","ControllerName")',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#contentDivId").html(data);
        },
        });
}
```

The controller method would look like this:

```
public ActionResult PartialViewMethod (string PartialViewName) {
     return PartialView("_" + PartialViewName);
}
```

Assuming that this is wrapped in a form submitting the name of the partial view you want to return, this would load the html from the partial view into the div with the id `contentDivId`.

Comment: In the above ajax call, if i have to refresh the entire view. Is there any method to do so, i mean in the ajax call i am updating a server side variable and it hides/shows some elements on the view , so i want the entire view to be refreshed after this ajax update, how can i do this?

Comment: If you want to refresh the entire page, then using partial views probably isn't what you want. However you could put the javascript to show/hide the elements in the `success: function` part of the call. Alternatively you could put code in the success function to actually load the other part of the page with another ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason of creating partial views if they are not required by multiple views, or loaded by ajax call. I would simply use two divs.